# remove colon in captions

Tags: graphics, captions

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%% \usepackage[latvian]{babel}                                                                                                                                                                              
%% \addto\captionslatvian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}}
%% the dot in "att." will replace ":" as the separator                                                                                                                                                 
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics{example-image-a}
      \caption{Case of A.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

How can I remove the colon from the caption of the image?

The case is relevant for some languages that have other means of separation (see the commented out lines of code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest, since `att.` (with the dot) seems to be an abbreviation, which will be used in cross-references, to use `labelsep=space`:

```
\documentclass{report}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage[latvian]{babel}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
 \addto\captionslatvian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}}
    %% the dot in "att." will replace ":" as the separator

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics{example-image-a}
      \caption{Case of A.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the help of the `caption` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage[latvian]{babel}                                                                                                                                                                              
     \addto\captionslatvian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{att}}
     \usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics{example-image-a}
      \caption{Case of A.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```