# package subfig interfering with caption setup of package caption

Tags: graphics, captions

Consider this example identified as a solution for [remove colon in captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473175/remove-colon-in-captions):

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{subfig}                                                                                                                                                                                        
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\addto\captionslatvian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{Case of A.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The command

`\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}`

fails once the line

`%\usepackage{subfig}`

is uncommented, i.e. the separator once again is `:`. How to solve?

Comment: Load  the `subcaption` package instead, and use its `subfigure` environment.

Comment: @Bernard, I am fixed to use `\subfloat` instead of `\subfigure`.

Comment: Use `labelsep=space` as an option on loading `subfig` then (cf. p. 31 of the documentation), if I've well understood the problem.

Comment: @Bernard, using `\usepackage[labelsep=space]{subfig}` didn't work, except when this line is moved after the line `\usepackage[latvian]{babel}`.

Comment: Load `subfig` *after* `caption`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `latvian.ldf` redefines `\@makecaption`. So load subfig after babel (you don't need to load caption, subfig is doing it):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup{labelsep=space}
\addto\captionslatvian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\tracingmacros=1
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{Case of A.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that a general recommendation?

Comment: No, also it is actually nonsense. subfig loads caption anyway. The problem is the latvian option of babel. I need to check this.

Comment: @Viesturs I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace \subfloat easily enough using a subfigure and a savebox.  Admittedly this version does not implement the list option, but that can be done using xparse or `\@ifnextchar[`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\addto\captionslatvian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}}

\newcommand{\subfloat}[2][\empty]% #1=caption (optional), #2=body
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#2}% measure image
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\wd0}
    \usebox0
    \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \else\caption{#1}
    \fi
  \end{subfigure}
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Case of A.]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```