# how to let caption adjust text to fill up the line

Tags: captions

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,floatfix,superscriptaddress,notitlepage]{revtex4-1}
```

I am using `\usepackage{subfig}`.

Problem arises after I use this package, the main caption look different than before.

I tried using package like `\usepackage{caption}` to adjust after reading some similar question.

The default setting `\captionsetup{justification=justified}` centers the caption and does not align right or left.

`\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}` makes the caption aligned to the left, but it does not adjust the text to make the text fill up the line so that the caption is also aligned to the right, like a normal paragraph.

I tried all the other options, none of them work good.

How can I make the caption aligned on both side, same like before I used `subfigure` package?

---

Update: I figured it out by myself.

`\captionsetup{justification=RaggedRight}` works, but I have to run the file twice.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473178/package-subfig-interfering-with-caption-setup-of-package-caption and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481768/compatibility-of-subfigure-with-subfig-package

Comment: Since you mention "normal paragraph" u may want to consider the package [`keyfloat`](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/keyfloat/keyfloat.pdf). \keyfig{..., t=<text>,...}{image}