# Same caption for two side-by-side figures

Tags: graphics

I want to place two different figures side by side, but I want the same caption under the figures and not two different ones. I'm using this code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{sinexeia}
        \captionof{figure}{Μελέτη του ορίου για ε=0.5 και δ=0.17.}
        \label{fig:test1}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{n.c.}
        \captionof{figure}{Μελέτη του ορίου για ε=0.5 και δ=0.3.}
        \label{fig:test2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Do you need ro reference each of the figure? And do you need a (a), (b) under each subfig?

Comment: The captions are *not* the same! Please, advise on what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be simpler to use `subfigure` environments (provided for example in [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)) rather than `minipage` environments. This way, you can choose to add a caption only for the whole figure, for individual subfigures, or for both. In the following example, I added captions for both for the sake of completeness, but you can just remove the `\caption` commands if you prefer to remove the captions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption for first subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption for second subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption for both subfigures as one figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another way. I prefer to use the `subfig` package which I think is a bit easier.
The subcaption is defined in the `[]` of the `\subfloat` command.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Caption for first subfigure]{
            \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \label{subfig:A}
        }\quad
        \subfloat[Caption for first subfigure]{
            \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \label{subfig:B}
        }
        \caption{Caption for both subfigures as one figure}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You realize that subcaption also supports \subfloat?  Not to mention https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473178/package-subfig-interfering-with-caption-setup-of-package-caption/473211?r=SearchResults&s=4|26.4375#473211

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do that is with the `floatrow` package. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
    \centering
    \ffigbox{\caption{Meret Oppenheim: Fur Cup.} \label{fig:test1}}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{dejeuner}}
        \ffigbox{\caption{Meret Oppenheim: Schoolgirl’s notebook. }\label{fig:test2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{cahierduneecoliere}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]