# Subfloat figure numbering like figures

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption

I am writing my thesis using a premade latex code that makes use of the subfig package and I want to place a series of images side by side two at a time. But this causes the image to have the caption numbered a, b, c.... or 1, 2, 3...., but I want the numbering to be the same as it would be for single images that follow the numbering of the chapter and sections:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{transparent} % Enables transparent images
\usepackage{eso-pic} % For the background picture on the title page
\usepackage{subfig} % Numbered and caption subfigures using \subfloat.
\usepackage{tikz} % A package for high-quality hand-made figures.
\usetikzlibrary{}
\graphicspath{{./Images/}} % Directory of the images
\usepackage{caption} % Coloured captions
\usepackage{xcolor} % Coloured captions
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xcolor} % Coloured "Theorem"
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{%
\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}%
}%

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[Figure 1]
{
   \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Figure 1.png}
   \label{fig:fig1}
}
\subfloat[Figure 2]
{
   \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Figure 2.png}
   \label{fig:fig2}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[Figure 3]
{
   \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Figure 3.png}
   \label{fig:fig3}
}
\subfloat[Figure 4]
{
   \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Figure 4.png}
   \label{fig:fig4}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have included all the packages I used because I am not sure which might matter.

Comment: Assuming you want to use the same counter, you will need as custom version of subfloat.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473178/package-subfig-interfering-with-caption-setup-of-package-caption/473211?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C26.4069#473211 and replace subfigure with minipage.

Comment: @JohnKormylo it says that the subfloat command is already defined and it shows the same caption as before. I tried removing the package subfig, that I am guessing is the one that defines subfloat in the first place it can't compile.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I would suggest taking a look at the `floatrow` package.

Answer (score 0):

The error came from your redefinition of `\thesubfigure`, which no longer exists.  Technically, you should replace the name `\subfloat` with something else, since it has nothing to do with subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}% REMOVE DRAFT OPTION
\usepackage{transparent} % Enables transparent images
\usepackage{eso-pic} % For the background picture on the title page
%\usepackage{subfig} % Numbered and caption subfigures using \subfloat.
\usepackage{tikz} % A package for high-quality hand-made figures.
\usetikzlibrary{}
\graphicspath{{./Images/}} % Directory of the images
\usepackage{caption} % Coloured captions
\usepackage{xcolor} % Coloured captions
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xcolor} % Coloured "Theorem"
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\newcommand{\subfloatlabal}{\empty}% reserve global name

\newcommand{\subfloat}[2][\empty]% #1=caption (optional), #2=body
{\bgroup
  \let\subfloatlabel=\empty
  \sbox0{% measure image
    \def\label##1{\gdef\subfloatlabel{##1}}% save \label name
    #2}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\wd0}
    \usebox0
    \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \else\caption{#1}%
    \fi
    \ifx\empty\subfloatlabel\relax
    \else\label{\subfloatlabel}%
    \fi
  \end{minipage}
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]% freinds don't let friends use [H]
\centering
\subfloat[Figure 1]
{
   \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Figure 1.png}
   \label{fig:fig1}

}
\subfloat[Figure 2]
{
   \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Figure 2.png}
   \label{fig:fig2}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat[Figure 3]
{
   \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Figure 3.png}
   \label{fig:fig3}
}
\subfloat[Figure 4]
{
   \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Figure 4.png}
   \label{fig:fig4}
}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig:fig1}, \ref{fig:fig2}, \ref{fig:fig3} and \ref{fig:fig4}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for this. What does removing [draft] do? Because if I do that my images break and it just shows the path to image and not the image

Comment: I added [draft] simply because I don't have your files on my computer and it turns off the resulting error messages.  Removing it should work the same as it used to.  I forgot to fmention: this \subfloat only supports \label in the caption, not the image (which is done first).

Comment: Never mind.  I figured out how to allow \label inside the image argument.